# How to copy single array from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have one multidimensional array as shown below(PHP) :

```
Array
(
    [144320] => Array
        (
            [3568728] => Array
                (
                    [30832] => 30832
                )

            [3568884] => Array
                (
                    [30827] => 30827
                    [30828] => 30828
                    [30830] => 30830
                    [30831] => 30831
                    [30832] => 30832
                    [30837] => 30837
                    [30838] => 30838
                    [30839] => 30839
                    [30826] => 30826
                    [30808] => 30808
                    [30806] => 30806
                    [30807] => 30807
                    [30698] => 30698
                    [30601] => 30601
                    [30697] => 30697
                )

        )

    [144330] => Array
        (
            [3568731] => Array
                (
                    [30827] => 30827
                    [30839] => 30839
                    [30838] => 30838
                    [30837] => 30837
                    [30832] => 30832
                    [30831] => 30831
                    [30828] => 30828
                    [30830] => 30830
                    [30826] => 30826
                    [30806] => 30806
                    [30808] => 30808
                    [30807] => 30807
                    [30698] => 30698
                    [30697] => 30697
                    [30601] => 30601
                )

        )

    [144218] => Array
        (
            [3568753] => Array
                (
                    [30808] => 30808
                )

        )

    [144216] => Array
        (
            [3568732] => Array
                (
                    [30808] => 30808
                )

        )

)
```

This array is populated by following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `bf_alert_stack` WHERE `type` = 'immediately'  order by created desc";

$q   = db_query($sql);

$user_alerts = array();

  while ($row  = db_fetch_array($q)) 
{   
   $user_alerts [$row['uid']]    [$row['alert_id']]  [$row['nid']] = $row['nid'];
}
```

From the above user_alerts array I want to rearrange the [$row['nid']] array and for rearrangement I want capture [$row['nid']] array and after capturing it into another array I want to re-arrange $row['nid'] array I want to update this $row['nid'] array into original user_alerts array.

How I can do this? I am not getting any search for this on google so just placed this on appropriate place.

Comment: Please show the desired output from your example data

Comment: Please describe what result you'd like and how  your question differs from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2?rq=1

Comment: as far as re arranging $row['nid']  is concerned u can do that by using  array_multisort($row['nid'], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
var_dump($ar);  but i am not sure what u mean by "I want to update this $row['nid'] array into original user_alerts array."

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to get it ordered from the query with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `bf_alert_stack` WHERE `type` = 'immediately' 
ORDER BY created desc, nid
```

But if you don't have access, or need the original sort for other reason, you need to iterate recursively over the array and reassign the last sortered level to the original array with PHP ksort method:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

```
foreach($user_alerts as $uid=>$user_alert) {
    foreach($alert as $alert_id=>$nids) {
        $user_alerts[$uid][$alert_id] = ksort($nids); 
    }   
}
```

Hope it helps!